# Mapper.CreateMap<> convert to AutoMapper version 5

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm studying a online class, and the instructor shows how to use de Mapper.CreateMap, I know that's deprecated, but I couldn't be able to use the new version, for lack of experience, so i want to learn the new way.

I've followed the instructor, by installing the version 4.2.1, and implementing what he did, but know i need help to convert this to the version 5, i've searched the internet, i tried to follow the documentation, but i couldn't do this right. I know that will need to reinstall the AutoMapper, i just need help with the code, please.

Thanks in Advance.

This are my codes:

```
    //Caminh -> Dominio para ViewModel
    public class DominioParaViewModelProfile : Profile
    {
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Usuario, UsuarioIndexViewModel>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Usuario, UsuarioViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

AutoMapperConfig (App_Start Folder)

```
    public static class AutoMapperConfig
    {
        public static void Configurar()
        {
            Mapper.AddProfile<DominioParaViewModelProfile>();
            Mapper.AddProfile<ViewModelParaDominioProfile>();
        }
    }
```

Global.asax

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AutoMapperConfig.Configurar();
        }
    }
```

UsuarioController

```
    public class UsuarioController : Controller
    {
        private SiteDbContext db = new SiteDbContext();

        // GET: Usuario
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(Mapper.Map<List<Usuario>, List<UsuarioIndexViewModel>>(db.Usuarios.ToList()));
        }

        // GET: Usuario/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Usuario usuario = db.Usuarios.Find(id);
            if (usuario == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(Mapper.Map<Usuario, UsuarioIndexViewModel>(usuario));
        }

        // GET: Usuario/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Usuario/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Nome,Email,Senha,Observacoes")] UsuarioViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Usuario usuario = Mapper.Map<UsuarioViewModel, Usuario>(viewModel);
                db.Usuarios.Add(usuario);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        // GET: Usuario/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Usuario usuario = db.Usuarios.Find(id);
            if (usuario == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(Mapper.Map<Usuario, UsuarioViewModel>(usuario));
        }

        // POST: Usuario/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Nome,Email,Senha,Observacoes")] UsuarioViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Usuario usuario = Mapper.Map<UsuarioViewModel, Usuario>(viewModel);
                db.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(viewModel);
        }

        // GET: Usuario/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Usuario usuario = db.Usuarios.Find(id);
            if (usuario == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(Mapper.Map<Usuario, UsuarioIndexViewModel>(usuario));
        }

        // POST: Usuario/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Usuario usuario = db.Usuarios.Find(id);
            db.Usuarios.Remove(usuario);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please describe the specific issue you're having problems with.

Comment: The specific issue is that i'm using a deprecated version of the framework, i tried to change the code to the new version (also installing the new version of the AutoMapper), but it doesn't work.

Comment: **What** doesn't work?  What is the actual problem you're experiencing?  Are you getting an error?  Is it doing nothing?  If you're getting an error, what line?  What is the exact text of the error message?  "It doesn't work" does not tell us anything useful.  We cannot see your screen to understand what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your profile is calling the wrong CreateMap - call the base CreateMap method on Profile instead, using the profile constructor:

```
public class DominioParaViewModelProfile : Profile
{
    public DominioParaViewModelProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Usuario, UsuarioIndexViewModel>();
        CreateMap<Usuario, UsuarioViewModel>();
    }
}
```